# How can I store and secure my JWT token in react application

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt

I'm using rest API, If I need to access those API endpoints need to authorize JWT Token. JWT tokens don't have any expiration so I can use anytime same token. Calling API through react application. Can anyone please help me with your idea where I can store JWT Token securely?

Comment: *JWT tokens don't have any expiration* - where did you get this idea? It's possible to create tokens without expiration, but that's usually not the case, most frameworks set an expiration time by default.

Comment: In my case, JWT doesn't have any automated expiration. So I should not store it cookies or local storage. Can you tell what are all the ways we can do? Thanks for your response.

Comment: if possible, you better add expiration. The [storage question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+store+jwt) comes up frequently, I don't think that there's anything to add that hasn't been written before.

Answer (score 1):

To do it properly, you should use session cookies and not store the tokens in the browser at all.

Instead you should consider using the BFF pattern as described here:

- https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc&t=13s&ab_channel=NDCConferences
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck

Comment: Old question, I know, but wouldn’t you still need to store the auth token locally for the BFF?